# Install kube-prometehus-stack get stuck on hook complication

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

We are trying to install `kube-prometheus-stack` and the installation get stuck (few hours) with the following message:

MESSAGE  `"waiting for completion of hook policy/PodSecurityPolicy/prometheus-kube-prometheus-admission and 6 more hooks "`  ,
is it a known issue?
what could be the reason? is there a way to avoid it?

https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack

Comment: What environment you are trying to install this with? Do you have any special config in values? Which helm version are you using?